# Python Multii User Auth

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to create a project in Python, Django. So I will be the admin. I will allow employer to create their system that allows their employee to login. How would I do so? I cant find any documentation on it. Employer will have to create employee account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're already somewhat familiar with Django, and know how to set the system up so that you can create users in the admin page as a superuser. If this is not the case, you would benefit from working through a couple of tutorials on YouTube or one of the courses on Udemy.

A couple of options you have, based on what I **think** you're trying to do:

1. You grant the employer staff/admin permissions and allow them to access the Django Admin page so that they can create additional users at will. This would be the easiest way, but could also be the most risky if they do not know what they're doing.
2. Create custom permissions groups: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/). If you don't want individual users to create their own accounts, you would need to set up views to allow those with the proper permissions to do it on their behalf.

There are several other options, but a lot of it is going to depend on how/where you plan to deploy your system and how complex you want the whole thing to be. Depending on the content, you might to look into [DjangoCMS](https://www.django-cms.org/en/), which could offer you everything you're looking for out of the box.

If you can be a bit more specific about A) how you plan to deploy, B) what type of content the site will serve, C) where you plan to deploy it, and D) how Django-savvy the employer will be, it would be easier to provide you with a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! I want to create a website that alot of company will be using. The company can manage their employee. So I will only be the admin. Its a employer to employee relationship only.